# display range of specified months with ncal

Tags: cal

Is it possible to display specific months in `ncal`? For example, `ncal -m1` will display January, but what if I want to display January and February? I've tried `ncal -m1,2` with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To display a range of months with `ncal` you have to use the following flags:

- `-m` to display the specified month.
- `-A` to add months after.
- `-B` to add months before.

To display January and February, you could use either:

```bsh
ncal -m1 -A 1
```

or

```bsh
ncal -m2 -B 1
```